# Problems with adding values to resx file with ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx, objectdatasource

I'm trying to connect resx file with object data source. However when I'm trying to add a value, it's not adding, but **replacing** an existent values. Could someone please give me a hint? What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
        Dictionary<string, string> resources = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public Dictionary<string, string> SelectIndex()
        {            
            using (ResXResourceReader resxreader = new ResXResourceReader(filename)) {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resxreader) {                    
                    resources.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            return resources;
        }

        public void AddIndex(Data data)
        {
            using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(filename)) {                
                resx.AddResource(data.Key, data.Value);                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is ResXResourceReader internally uses Dictionary, which can be seen from your foreach loop. In Dictionary every Key value should be unique, and if you are adding resources with same keys, it will update values for those keys.

[MSDN article about ResXResourceReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

[MSDN article about Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm using different Key value when editing. And when edited, even if file consisted of 3 values or more(all different), it replases all of them with the new one.